# Extract first date from filename using multiple patterns

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have an input file containing 1 string per line

input.txt (25k lines in reality)

```
one
two
three
```

Then i have a directory with many files (50 files in reality)

2022-04-01.csv

```
stuff;one;more_stuff
stuff;one;more_stuff
```

2022-04-02.csv

```
stuff;one;more_stuff
stuff;two;more_stuff
```

2022-04-03.csv

```
stuff;two;more_stuff
stuff;three;more_stuff
stuff;three;more_stuff
```

I need to extract the earliest date each pattern appears. So output in this case would be

```
one:2022-04-01.csv
two:2022-02-02.csv
three:2022-04-03.csv
```

I can use `grep -l one *.csv` to get me a unqiue list of files the pattern appears in, but not for multple patterns and not the single earliest date. If i could just get a list of files each pattern occurs in then i could manually extract the earliest date i think, but im sure there must be a 1 liner to do it all ?

Comment: I think doing so in a single reasonable line would require some form of `perl/awk` sorcery

Comment: How many patterns are there in the CSV files which are **not** contained in the `input.txt` file? Because disregarding the input list, you can get a full matching with this GNU Awk: `awk -F\; '!a[$2] {a[$2] = FILENAME} END {OFS=":"; for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' *.csv`

Comment: @pmf millions, I would think possibly half match

Comment: @Manse Then read the input file first, and preset the array with a filename that never occurs, e.g. `*`: `awk -F\; 'NR==FNR {a[$0]="*"; next} a[$2]=="*" {a[$2] = FILENAME} END {OFS=":"; for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' input.txt *.csv`

Comment: @pmf Nice. If the files are very large we could optimize with a counter and exit when all strings have been found.

Comment: @pmf change `a[$0]="*"` to just `a[$0]` and then use `$2 in a` rather than `a[$2]=="*"` as the latter will add every $2 value from all of the CSVs into `a`, making the script [potentially a lot] slower, use more memory, and then that `for (i in a)` loop in the END section would produce confusing and incorrect output as it'll print all of those $2 from the CSVs with no associated file names in addition to the desired output. Please post answers as answers instead of comments btw so they can be up/downvoted appropriately and have comments attached to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=";"; OFS=":" }
    NR==FNR {
        vals[$0]
        next
    }
    $2 in vals {
        print $2, FILENAME
        delete vals[$2]
    }
' input.txt *.csv
one:2022-04-01.csv
two:2022-04-02.csv
three;2022-04-03.csv
```

The `NR==FNR{...}` block stores all of values from input.txt as indices of the array `a[]` which I'm using as a hash table. The other block executes for every line read from the CSVs and tests if the current 2nd field from that line exists as an index in `a[]` (i.e. does a hash lookup) and, if so prints that value and the current file name then removes that index from `a[]` so no later occurrence of that same value can match.

This only works because your CSV file names are named in such a way that they will be passed to awk in the correct date order by your shell.

If and only if it's guaranteed that every value from input.txt will always appear in at least one of the CSVs then this would probably make the execution a bit faster most of the time, as suggested by @RenaudPacalet:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=";"; OFS=":" }
    NR==FNR {
        vals[$0]
        numVals++
        next
    }
    $2 in vals {
        print $2, FILENAME
        delete vals[$2]
        if ( --numVals == 0 ) {
            exit
        }
    }
' input.txt *.csv
```

Comment: Nice. I think `OFS` should be `:`, not `;`. And I would probably add `! length(vals) {exit}` for performance reasons.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Ah, I didn't see that the separator changed for the output, thanks I've fixed that now. Adding `! length(vals) {exit}` would generally make the script slower since awk would have to do that calculation for every line of every CSV until `vals` is empty. Even if we moved it to right after `delete vals[$2]` to reduce that impact it'd still only **possibly** make the script faster in the one scenario where all 25K of the values from input.txt appear in the CSVs early enough to make up for the length overhead and still slow it down if just one of those values was absent from all CSVs

Comment: Maybe a counter instead of `length`, and a test only after `delete`? Anyway, in order to check we would need a relevant example of the inputs.

Comment: A counter would reduce the impact but the resultant code would still be slower in all scenarios except the one where all 25 thousand values from `input.txt` exist in the CSVs so unless that's guaranteed to always be the case, I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I added a countdown-to-exit version and stated the caveat.

Comment: @EdMorton would you please be able to explain how that works, understand the first statement, your reading in the input file into an array, but how does the second statement work please ?

Comment: @Manse I added an explanation to my answer.